# Compile Qt5 application in QtCreator on Nixos (21.05)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator, nixos

I am trying to compile a Qt5 application from QtCreator on Nixos.

I have created the shell.nix file as described in https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Qt . I start QtCreator as follows:

```
$ ls -al
   ...
.rw-r--r--  236 username 30 Jun 17:31 shell.nix
   ...
$ nix-shell
[nix-shell:~/myproject]$ qtcreator
```

QtCreator starts and I can open my project file (myproject.pro).

However, when I "Build Project" [ctrl+b] I get the following error message:

```
9:38:09: Running steps for project myproject...
19:38:09: Starting: "/nix/store/gkr9j6p60vib8k8bxhc33581fn4pl8d8-qt-full-5.15.2/bin/qmake" /tmp/myproject/myproject.pro -spec linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=qml_debug
19:38:09: The process "/nix/store/gkr9j6p60vib8k8bxhc33581fn4pl8d8-qt-full-5.15.2/bin/qmake" exited normally.
19:38:09: Starting: "/nix/store/lxmh13cqvd2kwc3qbmnjknvynw6lc2si-gnumake-4.3/bin/make" -f /tmp/build-myproject-Desktop-Debug/Makefile qmake_all
make: Nothing to be done for 'qmake_all'.
19:38:09: The process "/nix/store/lxmh13cqvd2kwc3qbmnjknvynw6lc2si-gnumake-4.3/bin/make" exited normally.
19:38:09: Starting: "/nix/store/lxmh13cqvd2kwc3qbmnjknvynw6lc2si-gnumake-4.3/bin/make" -j16
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/nix/store/wn6q10flx0id4yxa96yq1jzpmbvi7d5r-qtwebkit-5.212.0-alpha4/lib -Wl,-rpath,/nix/store/wn6q10flx0id4yxa96yq1jzpmbvi7d5r-qtwebkit-5.212.0-alpha4/lib -Wl,-rpath,/nix/store/gpw8cms1ig5k16d86zr7hkhi77gccl9r-qtwebkit-5.212.0-alpha4/lib -Wl,-rpath,/nix/store/gpw8cms1ig5k16d86zr7hkhi77gccl9r-qtwebkit-5.212.0-alpha4/lib -Wl,-rpath,/nix/store/3sx0lss99gj0krp3xgqz47zipp8fmj18-qtbase-5.14.2/lib -o myproject cobs.o main.o mainwindow.o srm60binarycom.o moc_mainwindow.o   -L/nix/store/8jix4ismqsz2pz6gji3zpawdv2k5aqws-libGL-1.3.3/lib /nix/store/3sx0lss99gj0krp3xgqz47zipp8fmj18-qtbase-5.14.2/lib/libQt5Widgets.so /nix/store/3sx0lss99gj0krp3xgqz47zipp8fmj18-qtbase-5.14.2/lib/libQt5Gui.so /nix/store/3sx0lss99gj0krp3xgqz47zipp8fmj18-qtbase-5.14.2/lib/libQt5Core.so -L/nix/store/izvv5r9a8s19l742nfwr72z2w3ijq8bh-libglvnd-1.3.3/lib -lGL -lpthread   
/nix/store/qvc6cz5d43jhhm4a3r48xkrc82xh1s95-binutils-2.35.1/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/nix/store/qvc6cz5d43jhhm4a3r48xkrc82xh1s95-binutils-2.35.1/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:429: myproject] Error 1
19:38:09: The process "/nix/store/lxmh13cqvd2kwc3qbmnjknvynw6lc2si-gnumake-4.3/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project myproject (kit: Desktop)
When executing step "Make"
19:38:09: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

The errors:

```
.../ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
.../ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I seem to have the same issue when installing certain python packages (e.g. `scipy` when trying to build `numpy`). Would love to know if you solved this somehow.

Comment: Sorry, I never managed to solve this.
I simply went back to ArchLinux so I could get things done :-(

Nixos is a great idea, but it is not convenient to use (for me).

Answer (score 1):

This can be due to Qt Creator picking the bare gcc / g++ compiler instead of the wrapped versions. The wrapped version adds some command-line options to make things work.

In my case, I had to go into *Tools > Options > Kits* and switch the automatically selected C and C++ compilers from the "gcc" one to the "gcc-wrapper" one.

See related discussion at https://discourse.nixos.org/t/nix-shell-cmake-gcc-qt-creator-not-working-together/16703.

Answer (score 0):

I started Qt5 creator as (NixOS 23.05 ):
*export NIXPKGS_ALLOW_INSECURE=1*

*nix-shell -p qt5Full -p qtcreator --run qtcreator*

and ran same error as in this thread with generated QT Widget Application ("missing crt1.0")

The provided answer is ok, it just need some detailed steps:

1. Take a note from  QtCreator's *Tools > Options > Kits* auto-detected c and c++ paths
   (/nix/store/lcf37pgp3rgww67v9x2990hbfwx96c1w-gcc-wrapper-12.2.0/bin/gcc
   /nix/store/lcf37pgp3rgww67v9x2990hbfwx96c1w-gcc-wrapper-12.2.0/bin/g++)
2. Find *cmake* from /nix/store (/nix/store/0s8gvg6nh3d3cbby1hjf69jfb2xdvbvp-cmake-3.25.3/bin/cmake)
3. In UI Kits options "remove all" and then add manually c,c++ and Cmake using found paths.

After this compilation and running app was ok

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35113819)